# How to make android listview of edittext?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I want to make listview content edittext and button

any example code or project please.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this tutorial for Listview with Edittext :

[Android Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

and you can also edit item.xml for Button as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:id="@+id/ItemCaption"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" 
android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
<Button  android:id="@+id/add"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```